# How to restructure relationship data?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel 5.3 so bear with me ;)

I am using Laratrust for permission and roles, http://laratrust.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/configuration/models/user.html

I can do:

```
User::with('roles')->findOrFail( $id );
```

and get the user with the roles, but how can I get the user with a restructured variant of roles. Instead of the array with roles I want an array with a simplified variant of Role

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are asking for exactly.  Can you shed some more light on what you'd expect "a restructured variant of roles" to look like exactly?  What's different about the restructure than the original array of roles?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to find out what roles a **user with a specific** `id` has.

> Given `id` is the *id of the given user* try this -

```
User::find($id)->roles()
```

This will give you a list of **roles** the user with the given *id* has.